# Question regarding the use of the Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ be a $C^k$  function.   Suppose
>   $$
>     f(x)=(f_1(x), f_2(x), \cdots, f_{m+1}(x)) \quad \text{where} \quad det \; \left ( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (x)\right ) \ne 0 
>     $$
>   for $1\leq i,j \leq m$ for all $x \in U$.
>
> Prove that for every  $x \in U$, there exist  $W\subseteq U$ such that $f(W)$ is the graph of  a function $y_{m+1}=\varphi(y_1,y_2, \cdots, y_m)$ of class $C^k$.

I'm almost certainly sure we  need the implicit theorem to answer this, but since  $$f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$$ i have two questions:

1) Is it possible to resolve this exercise just the way it is?

2) What if I change $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ to $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ (just trying to see if the exercise was written incorrectly).

Comment: Looks like the dimensions of the domain and co-domain of $f$ should match (what you have under 2)), so that we are taking the determinant of a square matrix.

Comment: Oh yeah  that was a typo ill fix it now.

Comment: If the following helps any further:

If we tried the special case $m = 2$, we would have $U = ]a, b[$ (for simplicity, a connected open interval), the function
$$
f(x) = (f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x))
$$
would parameterize a smooth curve in the $y_1y_2$-plane, and the condition on the determinant would boil down to... what?  It should probably be something like
$$
\left.{df_{1} \over dx}\right|_{x = x_{0}} \neq 0,
$$
which is not analogous to the determinant of the total derivative of $f$ (which wouldn't even be a square matrix).

Comment: Thanks to point that out, I'll try to make it work when the domain and codomain have the same cardinality.